# Slider Like This

Tags: jquery, slider

Does anyone know of a jquery slider that looks and functions like this one?
http://www.virtualedgesummit.com/virtual-edge-summit-2011-sponsors/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [jQuery Tools Scrollable](http://flowplayer.org/tools/scrollable/index.html) will let you do this and a whole lot more. Check out the demos and the (really simple) code to set them up.

http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/scrollable/home.html

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about something like http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/ ? There are quite a few out there. Just google for **jquery** and **carousel**.